# Dynamic notification

Tags: android, notifications

I wanna put dynamic title of notification by calling R.string.app_name but i can't convert it in a CharSequence. R.string return a integer id that can not be compatible with notification.
Here's the try

```
CharSequence tickerText = R.string.app_name; //Error

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ico, tickerText,System.currentTimeMillis());
```

How i can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CharSequence tickerText = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
```